# Problems with urllib and urlparse on making calls

Tags: python

I am trying to make calls with a python script, and I followed some youtube videos, but when I run my script that show an error. I've been searching but I don't found an answer for this. Can u help me please??

Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urlparse'
I know that in python3 is urllib.parse but it still don't work

My code:

```
from twilio.rest import Client 
import os

account_sid = os.environ[""]
auth_token = os.environ[""]
from_number = ""
to_number = ""


client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
print("Call initiated")
call = client.calls.create(
    to=to_number, 
    from_=from_number,
    url= ""
)

print(call.sid)
```

Comment: Share the full stack of the error

Comment: I don't see a reference to `urlparse` in your code. Can you show the full traceback?

Comment: If that error is happening during `from twilio.rest import Client`, it sounds like the twilio module is expecting you to install the `urlparse` module.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you have to import urlparse at the beginning of your code.

```
import urlparse
```

Probably it is needed by twilio to work properly.